# When to remove file from git history?

Tags: git

I am developing a web application and noticed that I forgot to ignore a file that is being autogenerated by Gulp. I just added the path to the file to my `.gitignore` file. After executing these commands.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
```

The file then gets marked as deleted, but should I take it a step farther and run a command like this to completely remove the file from git history?

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path_to_file" HEAD
```

Is this necessary as it's not a file that holds any sensitive information (passwords, login credentials, etc)? Should I just leave the remnant of that file in the git history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a small file that was not changed often, so leaving it in the history causes no harm. There's no sensitive information in it either, so it will not cause problems.

Remove it in a new commit and call it a day, unless you are super-picky about the state of your historical commits.